# How to display the output in a vertical view dynamically?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am just running a **SQL query** to fetch a particular data from the database and would like to display in horizontal way inspite of the vertical format, Can we do something to display the data as required.

For Getting the clear understanding of the question i have attached the Output which i am getting and the output which i required after the SQL query is executed.

Thanks in Advance.

Query:

```
<?php
include 'connect-db.php';

$query = "SELECT distinct work_component FROM daily_progress_demo WHERE package_no='$package_no'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<center>".$row['work_component']."</center>";

echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr>"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<td>".$row['work_component']."</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $row['work_component']."<br>";
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.